# Python - Writing from a file to another file (Files not identically sorted)

Tags: python, file, function, dictionary, sorting

The code below allows me to pass through text files through the function and then output a newly created, third file containing the Username and Password as seen below:

File 1 Format(Username)

```
Username:ID:Name:Hash:::
```

File 2 Format(Password)

```
Hash:Password
```

File 3 Format(Newly created output file)

```
Username:Password
```

The current current code works perfectly well until the input files become not identically sorted causing the output files results to become unaligned and be incorrect. I basically want the Username and Password from the input files to be input into a new file and not screw up when they are not sorted correctly.

```
from itertools import izip

def merge(f1,f2,f3):

   with open(f3, "a") as outputFile:

      for line_from_f1, line_from_f2 in izip(open(f1), open(f2)):

         username = line_from_f1.split(':')[0]
         password = line_from_f1.split(':')[1]
         outputfile.write("%s:%s" % (username, password))

merge("input1.txt", "input2,txt", "output.txt")
```

I think dictionaries is the way to go but so far my attempts haven't succeeded and getting various key errors. Any help would be appreciated. :)

Best but produces Key Error:

```
def merge(f1,f2,f3):

   d1 = {}
   with open(f1, 'r') as f:
      for line in f:
         d1[line.split(':')[3]] = line.split(':')[0]

   d2 = {}
   with open(f2, 'r') as f:
      for line in f:
         d2[line.split(':')[0]] = line.split(':')[1]

   with open(f3, 'w') as f:
      for key in d1:
         f.write("{}:{}\n".format(d1[key], d2[key]))
```

Comment: Where is the best of your attempts, and how precisely did it not succeed (provide [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and full error traceback)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dict1 = {}
list1 = []
fs = ":"
with open("input1.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
       list1.append(line.rstrip('\n').split(fs))

with open("input2.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
      (key, val) = line.rstrip('\n').split(fs)
      dict1[key] = val   

with open("output.txt","w") as f:
    for username, id, name, hash, b1, b2, b3 in list1:
        if hash in dict1:
            f.write("%s:%s\n"%(username,dict1[hash]))
```

Comment: Thanks - it works when all of the usernames and passwords are paired, but if a username cannot be cracked it matches that username with the next password cracked and not get rid of the username that has no password as it wasn't successfully cracked.

Comment: Nope - works fine when all the passwords are cracked but when I add a test account into the first file with a bogus hash that won't get crack, the function pairs it with the password of the next cracked one.

Comment: It only outputs something if the hash of the input1.txt file is present in the second file. I can assure you it will never pairs a username with a wrong password.

Comment: I had it working now I'm getting `ValueError: too many values to unpack` for the `for username, id, name, hash, blank in list1:` ?

Comment: Nope, I tried adding another blank - but still gives the too many values to unpack error :S

Comment: Ok, i see you modified the format of the input1.txt file. You should simply use as many variable as the file contains per line.

Comment: I just added an extra `:` which the `blank2` should contemplate for - I don't know why its giving an error as all fields are being accounted for.

Comment: the number of variables is the number of : plus one.

Comment: `Username:ID:Name:Hash:::` means theirs 6 variables? and I have 'For username, id, name, hash, blank1, blank2 in list1` and it still doesn't work. I really don't have a clue why its not working, haha

Comment: There are 6 `:`, so there are 7 variables.

Comment: When adding `blank3` to the end, it doesn't give any errors but it also does work at all. The output.txt file is empty.

Comment: Any ideas how to fix this? I know you're probably sick of me by now but I really want to this work and I'm totally clueless with it now. :(

Comment: Nope :( Just produces a empty .txt file.